ASP.NET Core MVC with jquery beforeunload problem on ios
 function isEventTriggeredByLink(event) {
     var activeElement = document.activeElement;
     return activeElement && activeElement.tagName === 'A';
 }

 $(window).on('beforeunload', function (event) {
     if (!isEventTriggeredByLink(event)) {
         showLoadingScreen();
     }
 });

 $(window).on('pagehide', function (event) {
     if (!isEventTriggeredByLink(event)) {
         showLoadingScreen();
     }
 });

 document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function () {
     if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
         showLoadingScreen();
     } else if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
         hideLoadingScreen();
     }
 });

 $(window).on('load', function () {
     hideLoadingScreen();
 }); 

this code is not working only on the IOS when i reload the page i need to get the loading screen but it is not showing on other non IOS it is working fine how can i fix that
I have tried a lot of thinks that are for IOS like the page hide visibility change and other thinks but still when i refresh the page it is not showing the loading screen

beforeunload event is not supported by Mobile Safari. You can see the list of all supported events here: Handling Events Apple documentation

We can see a lot of reasons why Safari does not support beforeunload in the previous link, and we can identify the browser type, if ios devices, we can use visibilitychange, pagehide, pageshow events  to replace beforeunload event.

those are not working visibilitychange, pagehide, pageshow

So we can only look for other alternatives.

The problem is that i need this to be before the request because when i refresh the page the request will be made and i need to show the loading screen this was the only solution for this

To display a loading screen on iOS devices during page refreshes, implement an overlay that appears when the user navigates away. Create a full-screen overlay with CSS and trigger it using JavaScript on events like beforeunload （or unload）. This visually indicates a page transition, addressing iOS limitations with beforeunload.
